# Delete a node from chef client

Tags: chef-infra

I have connected to node with my chef server. I want to delete one from that node machine. I execute the knife delete command from that node. It shows

> ERROR: ArgumentError: Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that :node_name is assigned.

Is it possible to delete the node without knife configuration file?

Comment: Where are you trying to delete this node from? The node itself? Or your workstation? You should delete a node from the chef server or your machine, not the node itself.

Comment: trying to delete from the node itself

Answer (score 2):

Better way to delete clients from chef server is to do that from your workstation, it can be done with:

```
knife node delete NODE_NAME
```

Note, that deleting a node will not delete any corresponding API clients.

You can delete client manually with:

```
knife client delete CLIENT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

By default knife does not use the chef-client config files. You will have to explicitly point it via `knife -c /etc/chef/client.rb ...`. You'll also need to make sure that node has permissions to delete itself, which varies depending on which flavor of Chef Server you are running.